# What is needed in XSLT to add missing XML element?

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I am trying to transform an XML file into an updated version.

I have the following Source XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<config>
  <section name="abc">
    <key name="key1">My Key One</key>
  </section>
  <section name="def">
    <key name="key2">My Key Two</key>
  </section>
</config>
```

The transformation is to look like this... however, the target actually may already look like this, so I do not want section xyz added if already exists:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<config>
  <section name="abc">
    <key name="key1">My Key One</key>
  </section>
  <section name="def">
    <key name="key2">My Key Two</key>
  </section>
  <section name="xyz">
    <key name="key3">My Key Three</key>
  </section>
</config>
```

XSLT currently looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="config">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|text()|comment()|processing-instruction()">
<xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="config/section">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="config/section/key">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This appears to replicate what exists.  How do I get it to add my missing element if it is in fact missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="config">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      <xsl:if test="not(section/@name='xyz')">
        <section name="xyz">
          <key name="key3">My Key Three</key>
        </section>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:copy>    
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Actually, this did not work 100%.  if xyz was present, it added it again.  I got it to work by changing:

<xsl:if test="not(section/@name='xyz')">

to:

<xsl:if test="a[not(section/@name='xyz')]">

Comment: @clsturgeon - It worked 100% on your sample XML, but if you had to change it to `<xsl:if test="a[not(section/@name='xyz')]">` that means that `<config>` had a child `<a>` that contained the `<section>` (which isn't like the sample XML). Glad you figured it out though. :-)

Answer (score 3):

**Shorter and simpler (no explicit conditional instructions)**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="config[not(section[@name = 'xyz'])]">
  <config>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
   <section name="xyz">
     <key name="key3">My Key Three</key>
   </section>
  </config>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided source XML document:**

```
<config>
    <section name="abc">
        <key name="key1">My Key One</key>
    </section>
    <section name="def">
        <key name="key2">My Key Two</key>
    </section>
</config>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced (a new `section` is added):**

```
<config>
   <section name="abc">
      <key name="key1">My Key One</key>
   </section>
   <section name="def">
      <key name="key2">My Key Two</key>
   </section>
   <section name="xyz">
      <key name="key3">My Key Three</key>
   </section>
</config>
```

**when applied on this XML document**:

```
<config>
   <section name="abc">
      <key name="key1">My Key One</key>
   </section>
   <section name="def">
      <key name="key2">My Key Two</key>
   </section>
   <section name="xyz">
      <key name="key3">My Key Three</key>
   </section>
</config>
```

**again the wanted result is produced** (a new section isn't added, because it already exists):

```
<config>
   <section name="abc">
      <key name="key1">My Key One</key>
   </section>
   <section name="def">
      <key name="key2">My Key Two</key>
   </section>
   <section name="xyz">
      <key name="key3">My Key Three</key>
   </section>
</config>
```